# javascript defaults/fallbacks shorter solution

Tags: javascript, undefined, typeof

I use options in my javascript and it falls back to a default value if it does not exists:

```
var tabActive = typeof data.tabActive !== 'undefined' ? data.tabActive : 'active';
var paneActive = typeof data.paneActive !== 'undefined' ? data.paneActive : 'active';
```

However, with many rows like this it feels a bit messy/bloated. Is it possible to make it smarter with a helper function.

Something like this?

```
function option(key, value) {
  return 'Something';
}
```

Comment: You could also use `var tabActive = data.tabActive || 'active';`.

Comment: what values could `data.tabActive` have? just `undefined` or a string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could wrap the part for checking in a function.

```
function option(key, value) {
    return typeof data[key] !== 'undefined' ? data[key] : value;
}
```

For [falsy values](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy), like `undefined`, `null`, `''`, you could use a logical OR `||`. This returns the given `value`.

```
function option(key, value) {
    return data[key] || value;
}
```

Comment: I like your idea, but "data" is an outside reference, you should refactor this function to be implemented to any object. Data should be an argument, or you should create an own object reference like `this` .

Comment: @AndreCanilho, it depends. if the function is inside of the scope, then it works.

Comment: You are probably both correct about that. In my case data is global inside of a javascript module. I've not tried it yet but I guess this code will work in my case then.

Comment: @NinaScholz yes, but everytime you'll need the function, you'll have to redefine it inside the scope. It is not wrong, but it is a bad programming habbit.
If you have a default "check" accessible anywhee, you only define it once, and call it whenever you'll need .

Comment: @AndreCanilho, i see a small bit of code, not the whole code. you are right with *don't repeat yourself*.

Comment: Maybe hard to read in a comment, but I ended up with this in my scope 
fn.setOption('tabActive', 'active'); fn.setOption = function(key, value) { data[key] = data[key] || value; };

Answer (score 2):

If it's okay to treat any falsy value as though it were `undefined`, you can use the curiously-powerful `||` operator:

```
var tabActive = data.tabActive || 'active';
var paneActive = data.paneActive || 'active';
```

...but **not** if `""` is a valid value for them that you *don't* want converted to `"active"`, since `""` is a falsy value (the full list of falsy values is `0`, `NaN`, `null`, `undefined`, `""`, and of course, `false`).

Answer (score 0):

One alternative to Nina's solution. Notice I'm passing the object `obj` as an argument, alternatively you can also define this function as a property of your object `data`.

```
function testProp(obj, prop, val){
if(typeof obj !== 'undefined' && obj.hasOwnProperty(prop)){
    obj[prop] = val;
}
}
```

How to call the function:
    testProp(data, 'tabActive', 'active');